# Javascript - Get sub string starting and ending index from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, iteration, substring

Like I have a main string **"The world is awesome"**. So, I need to get starting and ending indexes of **"The world"** substring from the main string.

For example:

```
var mainString = "The world is awesome";
var subString1 = "The world";
StartIndex -> 0
EndIndex -> 8
var subString2 = "is awesome";
StartIndex -> 10
EndIndex -> 19
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `indexOf` to get the start index. Add the length of the substring minus 1 to get the end.

Comment: @Barmar you're absolutely right. That is quite simple! I must be overthinking! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Why down vote my question? It can be helpful for someone else, at least it got correct answers

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because you show no attempt to solve the problem yourself. "write code for me" questions are poor.

Comment: I got it but there're many simple questions on this platform with simple solutions, everyone needs directions sometimes. Thanks btw

Comment: Multiple wrongs don't make it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `indexOf` and add the substring length for the end

```js
var mainString = "The world is awesome";

const getStartEnd = (str, sub) => [str.indexOf(sub), str.indexOf(sub) + sub.length - 1]

console.log(getStartEnd(mainString, "The world"))
console.log(getStartEnd(mainString, "is awesome"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It's same as @Barmar direction, thanks mate!

Comment: what will happen if the mainString is ```The world is awesome and The world is beutiful```. how to get the second ```The world``` substring?

Comment: you'd need need to do something like `const [start1, end1] = getStartEnd(str, 'The world'); const [start2, end2] = getStartEnd(str.substr(end1), 'The world')`.  Or, if you always want the last one, just change `indexOf` to `.lastIndexOf`